# Alternative of 'unfortunately app has stopped'

Tags: android, android-debug

I want to know is there any way to know the cause of error or make android device to show the error details instead of just displaying the message 'Unfortunately App has stopped working' ?

Comment: What about reading the logcat?

Comment: Yeah I tried but couldn't find an app to display logcat correctly. If you know  then please suggest one

Comment: just connect it to your PC and it will show the LogCat there. Make sure you have USB Debugging enabled

Comment: I use android studio on that I run the app and select 'Attach debugger to android process' but that doesn't show me error when app crashed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the logcat on your IDE. Or using adb command, like `adb logcat`. It can also filter the message, if yout just want to see the error log, you can use `adb logcat *:E`. And another choice is to output the log file to sdcard, by using `adb logcat -f /sdcard/log.txt`.